# What app can I use to create mockups for websites? 

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a free or commercial software for Os X to create mockups for websites. Any suggestion?

Comment: Related: [Software for Website Mockups (Win/Linux)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12044/3474), [Web-based interaction tool for mockups](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3039/3474) at SR.SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Balsamiq Mockups is a good one, fairly cheap and very good - http://balsamiq.com/

Comment: The only downside of this app is, it is based on Adobe AIR. Sometime it gets your nerve (Like blocking the shutdown sequence). Otherwise, quite a neat mockup tool!

Answer (score 4):

You can do all sorts of fun things with [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) as well. And if you're looking for a way to make easy wireframes of current websites, you might do worse than checking out [Wirify](http://www.volkside.com/2010/12/introducing-wirify-the-web-as-wireframes/). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a cross-platform rapid wireframing tool.

Answer (score 2):

For mocking up websites I swear by [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/), it might be overkill, but the abilty to have a library of buttons etc and set a master page that carries elements to all the other pages, so headers/footers etc only need to be changed once.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [frame box](http://framebox.org/)—a "lightweight online tool for creating mockups."

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the definition of "mockup", you might be interested in [DENIM](http://dub.washington.edu:2007/denim/).

> DENIM is a system that helps web site
>   designers in the early stages of
>   design. DENIM supports sketching
>   input, allows design at different
>   refinement levels, and unifies the
>   levels through zooming.

Answer (score 2):

[Just In Mind](http://justinmind.com/) is probably one of the most extensive commercial website mockup apps, and [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/) is a fairly lightweight online mockup tool.

If you use Firefox 3, take a look at [Pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pencil/), a free wireframe sketching add-on. A version for Firefox 4 is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/pencil-ff4/), but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [SwordSoft Layout](http://www.swordsoft.idv.tw/). It also available on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swordsoft-layout/id438034858?mt=12)

Comment: Please summarize, the URL might die.